# How does realloc returns NULL when it failed to allocate memory?

Tags: null, dynamic-memory-allocation, c99, realloc, return-type

I am beginner in C. Currently I am learning about dynamic memory allocation. I have learned that void pointer returns nothing but when i got to know syntax of `realloc` I couldn't understand how it is returning NULL on failing to allocate memory

as per the standard the syntax of `realloc` is

```c
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t __size)
```

How does it return NULL when it fails to reallocate memory because it is void type.
for example

```c
const char *return_const_str(void) {
   char *str = "hello world";
   return str;
}
```

`return_const_str` returns pointer pointing to str because it's return type is *char but how is void even returning NULL in realloc?
I got very confused trying to understand it.

Comment: The return type is `void*`, not `void`. A `void*` is compatible with any pointer, and in particular it can hold a null pointer. C's economy of keywords means that `void` was reappropriated to mean "no specific type" here; it does of course not mean the pointer points to nothing (it *may*, but usually it points to something).